# C++ generate random number every time

Tags: c++, random, numbers, generator

I need to make a simulator for a college homework. In this simulator there are 3 computers, 2 of which send messages to computer 1 which then decides to either send the message or reject it. The rejection is random chance with 20% of rejection on computer 2 and 50% on computer 3. I use the rand()%100+1 function with the srand(time(NULL)) seed. It makes a random number however I need to run this multiple times and every time the same random number is used. For example if I run the simulation 12 times and the number generated is 45, 45 is used 12 times. I've both placed the random number generator inside the code and made a function outside.
How can you make a random number generator that generates a random number every time?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int randomgen()
{
int rndnum=0;
srand (time(NULL));
rndnum=rand()%100+1;
cout<< rndnum<<endl;
return rndnum;
}


struct comp1
{

int rejected=0; 
int received=0; 
int sent=0; 
int onhold=0; 


bool comp2reception()
{
    received++;
    bool result=false;
    int rndnum=0;
    srand (time(NULL));
    rndnum=rand()%100+1;

    if(rndnum<=20)
    {
        rejected++;
        result=false;
    }
    if(rndnum>=21)
    {
        onhold++;
        result=true;
    }
    return result;
}



bool comp3reception()
{
    received++;
    bool result=false;
    int rndnum=randomgen;

    if(rndnum<=50)
    {
        rejected++;
        result=false;
    }
    if(rndnum>=51)
    {
        onhold++;
        result=true;
    }
    return result;
}

};
```

Comment: You are not supposed to use `srand` more than once. Actually, you are not supposed to use it at all. Look at [this example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: you need to put srand once in the main function, and not in any other place

Comment: If you call `srand` with the same seed value every single time you ask for a random number, you'll get the same number. Move the call to `srand` to the top of your `main` function where it will only be called once when your program starts.

Comment: You're supposed to use `srand()` once and then use `rand()` everywhere else.

Comment: It was exactly that, using srand() only once in the main. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `srand(time(NULL))` just once at the beginning of the program.

Since `time()` return number of seconds from 1970 and you program probably takes less than that to finish, you esentially reset the generator with same value before each call. Which of course returns same (first) value each call.

Answer (score 3):

Use the C++11 header `<random>`.

```
#include <random>

static std::random_device rd;
static std::mt19937 gen(rd());

int randomgen()
{
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0,100);
  int rndnum = dis(gen);
  std::cout << rndnum << std::endl;
  return rndnum;
}
```